# Correct way to pass in custom model parameters for RLLib model?

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I have a basic custom model that is essentially just a copy-paste of the default RLLib fully connected model (https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/models/tf/fcnet.py) and I'm passing in custom model parameters through a config file with a `"custom_model_config": {}` dictionary. This config file looks as follows:

```
# Custom RLLib model
custom_model: test_model

# Custom options
custom_model_config:
  ## Default fully connected network settings
  # Nonlinearity for fully connected net (tanh, relu)
  "fcnet_activation": "tanh"
  # Number of hidden layers for fully connected net
  "fcnet_hiddens": [256, 256]
  # For DiagGaussian action distributions, make the second half of the model
  # outputs floating bias variables instead of state-dependent. This only
  # has an effect is using the default fully connected net.
  "free_log_std": False
  # Whether to skip the final linear layer used to resize the hidden layer
  # outputs to size `num_outputs`. If True, then the last hidden layer
  # should already match num_outputs.
  "no_final_linear": False
  # Whether layers should be shared for the value function.
  "vf_share_layers": True

  ## Additional settings
  # L2 regularization value for fully connected layers
  "l2_reg_value": 0.1
```

When I start the training process with this setup, RLLib gives me the following warning:

> Custom ModelV2 should accept all custom options as **kwargs, instead
> of expecting them in config['custom_model_config']!

I understand what **kwargs does, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it with a custom RLLib model to fix this warning. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear how you're actually passing the custom configuration values. This post contains code about changing the model, e.g. number of nodes/hidden layer and might be helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/ray-and-rllib-for-fast-and-parallel-reinforcement-learning-6d31ee21c96c

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: add `**customized_model_kwargs` in your network `__init__` and then get back your custom config from that.

---

I will explain you what to do to avoid this warning.

When you use a custom network, you are certainly using something like:

```
policy.target_q_model = ModelCatalog.get_model_v2(
        obs_space=obs_space,
        action_space=action_space,
        num_outputs=1,
        model_config=config["model"],
        framework="torch",
        name=Q_TARGET_SCOPE)
```

The model is instantiated like this by Ray (see the ModelCatalog https://docs.ray.io/en/master/_modules/ray/rllib/models/catalog.html):

```
instance = model_cls(obs_space, action_space, num_outputs,
                                         model_config, name,
                                         **customized_model_kwargs)
```

Therefore you should declare your network like this:

```
  def __init__(self, obs_space: gym.spaces.Space,
               action_space: gym.spaces.Space, num_outputs: int,
               model_config: ModelConfigDict, name: str, **customized_model_kwargs):
    TorchModelV2.__init__(self, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs,
                          model_config, name)
    nn.Module.__init__(self)
```

Notice the `customized_model_kwargs` arg.

Then you can use `customized_model_kwargs["your_key"]`to have access to your custom configs.

Note: It would be similar for TF

Answer (score 1):

You can pass custom model parameters by setting the `"custom_model_config"`, which is part of the model config. By default it's empty.

From the [docs](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib-models.html#default-model-config-settings):

```py
# Name of a custom model to use
"custom_model": None,
# Extra options to pass to the custom classes. These will be available to
# the Model's constructor in the model_config field. Also, they will be
# attempted to be passed as **kwargs to ModelV2 models. For an example,
# see rllib/models/[tf|torch]/attention_net.py.
"custom_model_config": {},
```

Your custom model has a `model_config` argument in its constructor.
You can access the model params via `model_config["custom_model_config"]`.

---

Example:

```py
# setting custom params
config = ppo.DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy()
config["model"] = {
  "custom_model": MyModel,
  "custom_model_config": {
    "my_param": 42
  }
}
...
trainer = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, env=MyEnv)
```

Inside `MyModel`:

```py
class MyModel(TFModelV2):
  def __init__(self, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs, model_config, name, **kwargs):
    self.my_param = model_config["custom_model_config"]["my_param"]
```